# What are these Horadric runes in the corner of Overwatch?

Tags: overwatch

After a particularly successful game of Overwatch I went to watch my highlight of the match since I enjoy inflating my ego like a bouncy castle. After having done that I went back to the main menu and glimpsed rapidly changing characters at the bottom left of the screen. (See below)

[image: first screenshot]

[image: second screenshot]

[image: third screenshot]

This set of characters appeared every time I went to highlights and back to the main menu but not for any other menu option. However, upon restarting the game it no longer appeared. The last number that is changing appears to go from around 4000 to 0 and then repeats once before the characters disappear.

What are these characters? Is it a hidden message? Is it just loading something?

Comment: *"I went to watch my highlight of the match since I enjoy inflating my ego like a bouncy castle"*; I'll save that one for later use :D

Comment: Sombra. It was Sombra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't speak with 100% certainty nor do I have any source for this, but I believe they have something to do with resources when loading into a game as I see them most frequently there. Before these were added, and if the game takes longer than expected to load (as I run a potato), I'd get kicked for inactivity ... I believe these make sure the server knows I'm actively loading and waiting to play and not simply be afk.

TLDR; It seams to be a blizard way of a loading progress.

Comment: I can confirm this. This number goes down as the amount of ressources to be loaded decreases. When I first start the game there is neither a character nor a map there to look at. After the number is gone, it takes a few more seconds and then everything shows. Same goes for actual matches.